# Changing url dynamic JS

Tags: javascript, url

I have a URL which should be changing dynamically.
The number 2 is dynamic.

```js
const API_Albums = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2/albums`


class Main extends Component { 
...

  fetchAlbums(id) {
        axios.get(API_Albums+id/albums)
            .then(result => {
               .....
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

How can I change only the id's part of URL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript concatenate variable to url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7767687/javascript-concatenate-variable-to-url)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```js
class Main extends Component { 
...

  fetchAlbums(id) {
        axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}/albums`)
            .then(result => {
               .....
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

### Edit

Example using a function outside of the get to make the dynamic url

```js
const buildUrl = id => `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}/albums`
class Main extends Component { 
...

  fetchAlbums(id) {
        axios.get(buildUrl(id))
            .then(result => {
               .....
            })
            .catch(error => console.log(error)
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to do that not inside get function?

Comment: you could make a function to do it, i'll add an edit